# jQuery setTimeout ajax recursive function throwing error after short while in instant messaging program

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Like the title says, I'm writing an instant messaging program using jquery, ajax, mysql and php.  Currently, I have a database with a table "switchboard" that contains the fields

mid*, from, to, message, timestamp, read

I have a function that uses setTimeout to recursively check every 1 to 3 seconds for new unread messages that is as follows:

```
function get_new_messages(){
    if( $('input[name="from"]:checked').val()
        && $('input[name="to"]:checked').val()
        && ready) {

        ready=false;
        //ajax call
        $.ajax({
            url: 'chatAjax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                checker_from:$('input[name="from"]:checked').val(),
                check_to: $('input[name="to"]:checked').val()},
                success: function(data){
                    $('#chat_window').append(data);
                    ready=true;

            setTimeout(get_new_messages,1000);
                },
                error: function(){
                    ready=true; 
            setTimeout(get_new_messages,3000);
            }               
        }
        );
    } else{
        setTimeout(get_new_messages,3000)
    }
}
```

Right now I'm only testing, so checker_from and check_to correspond to radio buttons that contain a username. Using two browser windows I am attempting to send messages from one window to the other, however, after a while, the console shows consistent POST failures.  Is this a memory leak, or something else.  any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: i see you are new to stackoverflow, welcome! However, this isn't like a forum, and seeing "hi" in the title is a little strange, titles are usually just a title on SO

Comment: under the network tab in the chrome dev tools, its just says (failed) under the status column, and under the Initiator column I get jquery.js:8706, which is xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );

Comment: Probably the server fighting you back

Comment: what would cause it to do that?  I should also mention I have a submit button that writes a new message to the switch board via insert. when my setTimeout function fails though, it does not allow the write to take place either

Comment: Look at the error log, look at what comes back from the server.

Comment: POST *url of the processing php file for the request*
send
x.extend.ajax
get_new_messages.



changing get_new_messages to get_new_messages() doesn't help, although I'm wondering if setTimeout requires the use of an anonymous function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider using Node.js and Socket.IO.  It is much more efficient.  [My book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617290750) goes over how to do this in full detail, but there are many Node/Chat demonstrations on the web.  You could just use Node for the chat server and PHP for everything else.

The reason you are seeing POST errors is probably due to the constant polling that you are doing.  Browsers generally have a limit on the number of concurrent connections to a given server.  Traditionally, a domain was limited to 2 concurrent connections, although that is changed now in some browsers (I'm thinking Chrome).  I suspect your are seeing errors when the POSTs start to "run over" each other and exceed the limit.  Besides, polling like this will quickly kill a server in a mult-user system.

Instead of constantly polling, you want something that handles push messaging, like web sockets and long-polling fall-back. The Socket.IO and Strophie libraries provide this.  I have experience with Strophie/XMPP - and I can confirm that it is a LOT more complicated. Socket.IO scales easily to thousands (or tens of thousands) per server.  The solution you are currently pursuing is nowhere near as scalable :)

Comment: thanks, I'll look into this instead.  It definitely seems to be a polling issue, as the code runs fine for a while, and then just doesn't, even though the requests are essentially identical

Comment: Everything you're saying is true, node and socket.io is better than the OP's solution, but this doesn't really look like an answer, it looks more like a shameless plug to promote your book, and just a comment saying "node with socket.io is better", would have been better IMO.

Comment: @adeneo First, I think this is very much a good, detailed answer based on lots of experience with web messaging.  Second, I have hundreds of comments and posts on Stackoverflow, and this is the only time I have ever linked to my book.  I did so only because it is so relevant - the book shows exactly how to set up a near-production-grade chat server. Finally, "but there are many Node/Chat demonstrations on the web" illustrates there are many free resources on the web that cover the same issue.  I am sorry if the response still came across as shameless to you.

Comment: FWIW, the book mentioned is excellent. It clearly explains the concepts involved rather than focusing solely on a specific framework.